# notifyDataSetChanged not working with Custom RecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I can't seem to get my RecyclerAdapter to respond to adding data properly. 
Here is my Activity that uses the RecyclerView

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
FloatingActionButton fab;
FloatingActionMenu fam;

//startActivity(intent);

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
ArrayList<TeamInfo> teamsInfo;
SelectedTeamsRecyclerAdapter adapter;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /*if(savedInstanceState == null) {

        if(teamsInfo == null) {
            Log.d("TEAM SELECTION", "teams Info == null");
            teamsInfo = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
    else {
        if(teamsInfo == null) {
            teamsInfo = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("selectedTeams");
        }

    }*/
    teamsInfo = new ArrayList<>();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.menu_item);
    fam = (FloatingActionMenu) findViewById(R.id.menu);
    fam.setClosedOnTouchOutside(true);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            addClicked();
        }
    });




    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.selected_teams_recyclerview);
    adapter = new SelectedTeamsRecyclerAdapter(this, teamsInfo);
    adapter.setHasStableIds(true);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    //teamsInfo = TeamInfo.restoreTeamInfo(this);


    //adapter.setHasStableIds(true);


    //mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);

    //DragSortRecycler dragSortRecycler = new DragSortRecycler();
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new HorizontalDividerItemDecoration.Builder(this).build());
    //mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(dragSortRecycler);
    //mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(dragSortRecycler.getScrollListener());
    //dragSortRecycler.setViewHandleId(R.id.selected_teams_draghandle); //View you wish to use as the handle


    /*dragSortRecycler.setOnItemMovedListener(new DragSortRecycler.OnItemMovedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemMoved(int from, int to) {
            itemMoved(from, to);
        }
    });
    */

}

public void itemMoved(int from, int to) {
    TeamInfo item = teamsInfo.remove(from);
    teamsInfo.add(to, item);
    adapter.notifyItemInserted(teamsInfo.size() - 1);
}

public void addClicked() {

    fam.close(true);
    getNewTeamValues();

    //Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewTeamActivity.class);


}

public void addNewTeam(String teamName, int primaryColor, int secondaryColor) {
    teamsInfo.add(new TeamInfo(teamName, primaryColor, secondaryColor));
    //adapter.mTeamsInfo.add(new TeamInfo(teamName, primaryColor, secondaryColor));
    //adapter.addItem(new TeamInfo(teamName, primaryColor, secondaryColor));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void getNewTeamValues() {


    TextView nameTV;s
    MaterialDialog dialog  = new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
            .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                    // TODO

                    LineColorPicker primaryColorPicker = (LineColorPicker) dialog.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.primaryColor);
                    LineColorPicker secondaryColorPicker = (LineColorPicker) dialog.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.secondaryColor);
                    EditText newTeamNameEditText = (EditText) dialog.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.teamNameEditText);
                    View v = dialog.getContentView();
                    String teamName = newTeamNameEditText.getText().toString();
                    int primaryColor = primaryColorPicker.getColor();
                    int secondaryColor = secondaryColorPicker.getColor();

                    addNewTeam(teamName, primaryColor, secondaryColor);

                }
            })
            .title("Enter Team Info")
            .customView(R.layout.dialog_new_team, true)
            .positiveText("Add")
            .negativeText("Cancel").build();

    dialog.show();
}




}
```

And here is my Custom Adapter

```
public class SelectedTeamsRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SelectedTeamsRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>{

public ArrayList<TeamInfo> mTeamsInfo;
Context mContext;

public SelectedTeamsRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<TeamInfo> teamsInfo) {
    mTeamsInfo = teamsInfo;
    mContext = context;

}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView teamNameTV;
    public View primaryColorV;
    public View secondaryColorV;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        teamNameTV = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected_teams_teamname);
        primaryColorV = (View) itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected_teams_primarycolor);
        secondaryColorV = (View) itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected_teams_secondarycolor);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mTeamsInfo.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    TeamInfo teamInfo = mTeamsInfo.get(position);
    holder.teamNameTV.setText(teamInfo.getTeamName());
    holder.primaryColorV.setBackgroundColor(teamInfo.getPrimaryColor());
    holder.secondaryColorV.setBackgroundColor(teamInfo.getSecondaryColor());

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.selected_teams_list_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public void addItem(TeamInfo teamInfo) {
    mTeamsInfo.add(teamInfo);

}

/*public ArrayList<TeamInfo> getTeamsInfo() {
    return this.teamsInfo;
}*/


}
```

I've written almost the exact same code in the past and everything worked out fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of All you didn't add `mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager )`
try to add and let me know if you have any problem again.

Comment: Oh my god. I spent hours last night trying to figure this out.. That's what I get for coding at 3:00AM.